# Sprite flickering behind 3d Content, cocos3d

Tags: ios, cocos3d

In the Cocos3d app that I´m working on, I have several sprites added into the CC3Layer. This sprites are rendered behind the 3d content, and each time I touch the screen, the 2d content flickers. I´ve tried turnning on the prorpety on the CC3Scene , self.shouldClearDepthBuffer=YES; and  telling the director in the same CC3Scene to setDepthTest [[CCDirector sharedDirector]setDepthTest:YES];. But no way, it still flickers, and the efect is more noticeable in old devices like Ipod touch 4. I´ve discarded to work with CC3BillBoards, because doesn´t fills the needs of the app. However, if the content is rendered overlaying the 3d content, no flicker happens when a touch happens. Does anybody experienced something like this? Is there a way to solve it?
Thanks.
Carlos.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a bunch of textured rectangles in the background, you can simply create them as such using `populateAsCenteredRectangleWithSize:`, or similar method on the `CC3MeshNode`. See how the `addGround` method in `CC3DemoMashUpScene` creates the ground.

Try to avoid using `CC3Billboards` for that. `CC3Billboards` are used to hold *cocos2d* sprites or 2D particle generators. Unless you already have a 2D sprite or particle generator that you must use in the 3D scene, you should simply create your meshes in the 3D world directly It is ***much*** more efficient, because there is overhead in switching back and forth between 2D and 3D rendering.

Is your camera moving around, or static?

If you need these background images to track the camera, you can use the `asCameraTrackingWrapper` on each, or simply set the camera as the target of your image rectangle nodes, and set the `shouldTrackTarget` property to `YES`.